# Jetpack Compose - preserve state of AndroidView on configuration change

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Most likely a newbie question, as i'm fairly new to Android dev - I am having troubles preserving the state of AndroidView in my @Composable on configuration change/navigation , as factory block is called (as expected) and my chart gets reinstantiated.

```
@Composable
fun ChartView(viewModel:ViewModel, modifier:Modifier){
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val chart = remember { DataChart(context) }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            Log.d("DEBUGLOG", "chart init")
            chart
        },
        update = { chart ->
            Log.d("DEBUGLOG", "chart update")
        })
}
```

The `DataChart` is a 3rd party component with a complex chart, i would like to preserve the zoom/scrolling state. I know i can use ViewModel to preserve UI state across conf. changes, but given the complexity of saving zoom/scrolling state, i'd like to ask if there is any other easier approach to achieve this?

I tried to move the whole chart instance to viewModel, but as it's using context i get a warning about context object leaks.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have just updated my answer, please check it and give me a feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your instincts were correct to move the chart instance into the view model, but, as you noted, context dependencies can become a hassle when they are required for objects other than views. To me, this becomes a question of dependency injection where the dependency is the context or, in a broader sense, the entire data chart. I'd be interested in knowing how you source your view model, but I'll assume it relies on an Android view model provider (via `by viewModels()` or some sort of `ViewModelProvider.Factory`).

An immediate solution to this issue is to convert the view model into a subclass of an [`AndroidViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel) which provides reference to the application context via the view model's constructor. While it remains an anti-pattern and should used sparingly, the Android team has recognized certain use cases to be valid. I personally do not use the `AndroidViewModel` because I believe it to be a crude solution to a problem which could otherwise be solved with refinements to the dependency graph. However, it's sanctioned by the official documentation, and this is only my personal opinion. From experience, I must say its use makes testing a view model quite a nightmare after-the-fact. If you are interested in a dependency injection library, I'd highly recommend the new [`Hilt`](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack) implementation which recently launched a stable `1.0.0` release just this past month.

With this aside, I'll now provide two possible solutions to your predicament: one which utilizes the `AndroidViewModel` and another which does not. If your view model already has other dependencies outside of the context, the `AndroidViewModel` solution won't save you much overhead as you'd likely already be instantiating a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` at some point. These solutions will be considering the scope of an Android `Fragment` but could easily be implemented in an `Activity` or `DialogFragment` as well with some tweaks to lifecycle hooks and whatnot.

**With `AndroidViewModel`**

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel

class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val dataChart: DataChart

    init {
        dataChart = DataChart(application.applicationContext)
    }
}
```

where the fragment could be

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View { ... }
}
```

**Without `AndroidViewModel`**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MyViewModel(args: Args) : ViewModel() {

    data class Args(
        val dataChart: DataChart
    )

    val dataChart: DataChart = args.dataChart
}
```

where the fragment could be

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val applicationContext: Context = requireContext().applicationContext
        val dataChart = DataChart(applicationContext)

        val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels {
            ArgsViewModelFactory(
                args = MyViewModel.Args(
                    dataChart = dataChart,
                ),
                argsClass = MyViewModel.Args::class.java,
            )
        }

        this.viewModel = viewModel

        ...
    }
}
```

and where `ArgsViewModelFactory` is a creation of my own as shown below

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class ArgsViewModelFactory<T>(
    private val args: T,
    private val argsClass: Class<T>,
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = modelClass.getConstructor(
        argsClass,
    ).newInstance(
        args,
    )
}
```

**edit (via Hilt module):**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(...)
object DataChartModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideDataChart(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    ): DataChart = DataChart(context)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an extensive response and valuable insights. I'm using Hilt(Dagger) for DI  and no fragments (pure one activity compose app with nested navigations), i'll try to apply some of the concepts you've suggested.

Comment: Oh cool! If you are using Hilt, please checkout the @ApplicationContext annotation documentation. You should be able to inject an instance of the DataChart directly because Hilt provides an easy way to reference the application context. I'll edit my answer to indicate what that might look like.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm concerned about this approach in general tho, as injecting context in viewmodel in general is not recommended practice as it can lead (as indicated by android studio itself as well) to memory leaks.

Comment: Your edit works like a charm and the state is now persistent. I'm still worried a bit about the memory leaks, even tho i don't see any warnings in Studio. I've run a profiler / heap dump and don't see any memory leaks so far, so hopefuly it will be ok. Once again thanks, i will accept this as an answer.

Comment: While the DataChart is referencing context, it's referencing the application context which is a singleton with a lifecycle identical to that of the application. This is different from passing the activity or some form of the activity context. As far as I am aware, this will never lead to a memory leak which is why the Android team themselves introduced the `AndroidViewModel`.

Comment: Functionally, utilizing Hilt's @ApplicationContext annotation is identical to the usage of an `AndroidViewModel`. While it's a great idea to check for leaks, I believe this to be an intended use case, and I've employed this approach for injecting an `AppUpdateManager` into a Fragment in the past without leaks.

Comment: Brilliant, once again thanks for your help and useful explanations.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preserve state of AndroidView on configuration change, Use `rememberSaveable` instead `remember`.

> While **remember** helps you retain state across recompositions, the state
> is not retained across configuration changes. For this, you must use
> **rememberSaveable**. **rememberSaveable** automatically saves any value that
> can be saved in a Bundle. For other values, you can pass in a custom
> saver object.

If the DataChart is a type of Parcelable, Serializable or other data types that can be stored in bundle :

```
val chart = rememberSaveable { DataChart(context) }
```

If the above way not working then create a MapSave to save data, zoom/scrolling states... I assume the DataChart has zoomIndex, scrollingIndex, values properties which your need to save:

```
fun getDataChartSaver(context: Context) = run {
    val zoomKey = "ZoomState"
    val scrollingKey = "ScrollingState"
    val dataKey = "DataState"

    mapSaver(
        save = { mapOf(zoomKey to it.zoomIndex, scrollingKey to it.scrollingIndex, dataKey to it.values) },
        restore = { 
            DataChart(context).apply{
               zoomIndex = it[zoomKey]
               scrollingIndex = it[scrollingKey]
               values = it[dataKey]
            } 
        }
    )
}
```

Use:

```
val chart = rememberSaveable(stateSaver = getDataChartSaver(context)){ DataChart(context) }
```

See more [Ways to store state](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#ways-to-store)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. DataChart can grow quite big depending on data (supports multiple datasets etc.) so i'm not sure if it's a good approach to save it in Bundle() via rememberSaveable.. I will look into custom saver, which might be a better option in my case.

Comment: Almost no third party components that provide advanced functionality is going to be  serializable, so this solution is kind of useless.

Comment: I'm getting a compile-time error `Unresolved reference: mapSaver`. Are there any necessary dependencies?

Comment: Have you checkout this document https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#ways-to-store yet? I think there is no need to add any dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest way I know of. This keeps the state and doesn't trigger a reload on the WebView when I rotate my phone. It should work with every View.

First create an application class

```
class MainApplication : Application() {

    private var view: WebView? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        LOG("started application")
    }

    fun loadView(context: Context): WebView {
        if (view == null) {
            view = WebView(context)
            //init your view here
        }
        return view!!
    }
}
```

Then add the application class to `manifest.xml`

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
    ...
```

Finally add this to the composable

```
AndroidView(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), factory = { context ->
    val application = context.applicationContext as MainApplication
    application.loadView(context = context)
})
```

That's it. I'm not sure if this can lead to memory leaks but I haven't had problems yet.